# Multiple regexp replace in string

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I need to search for every declared variable in a string with format `%^{var}`, prompt a value and replace in place.

```
(let ((primitive "(%^{size}, %^{center})"))
  (if (string-match "%^{\\([^}]*\\)}" primitive)
      (replace-regexp-in-string (format "%%^{%s}" (match-string 1 primitive))
                                (read-string (format "%s: " (match-string 1 primitive)))
                                primitive))
  (message "%s" primitive))
```

However this does not replace the variable in the string and the primitive is printed unchanged.

(Later when I fix this problem, I'm changing `if` to `while` so it does it for every variable in the string)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the return value of `replace-regexp-in-string`.

Comment: Fuck me. Rookie mistake.

Comment: We've all been there :)